# What all things change after each Manvantara?

Tags: brahma, creation, kalpa, manvantara

Like I know that the names of Manu changes. So does the name of Indra and the Saptarishis. What other things/names change ?
And are all events of each kalpa identical to each other ?

Comment: History never repeats. That's why they are different. That's why kalpa can't be same

Comment: Some major events are bound to happen @sbharti